# How do I run a specific Behat scenario

Tags: php, behat

I'm trying to run a specific Behat scenario from the command line, here's what I'm doing:

```
$ bin/behat features/features/baseline.feature:3
```

However this isn't picking up the scenario.

If I run

```
bin/behat features/features/baseline.feature
```

I can get the entire feature file to run.

Here's what the file looks like -- the scenario I'm trying to run is on line 3 in my text editor:

```
Feature:
  @api
  Scenario: Clear cache
    Given the cache has been cleared
    When I am on the homepage
    Then I should get a "200" HTTP response

  Scenario:
    Given I am not logged in
    When I am on the homepage
    Then I should see the text "We love our users"
```

Answer (score 56):

First of all you should add the whole description of the feature file, like:

```
Feature: Home page functionality
  In order to use application functionality
  As a website user
  I need to be able see the home page
```

And `Scenario` should also has a description.

You can run behat scenarios using tags:

```
bin/behat --tags @api
```

Basically every `Scenario` could has own tag. Behat command will try to find all scenarios with that `@api` tag.

Also you can specify tag for the whole Feature file:

```
@whole-feature-file
Feature: Home page functionality
```

Run Scenario using part of the name:

```
bin/behat --name="element of feature"
```

Or according to the @greggles comment:

Specify the feature file name and line number, e.g.

```
bin/behat features/file.feature:123
```

where 123 is the line number of the line like `Scenario: Clear cache`

For more details see [behat docs](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/6.cli.html#gherkin-filters)

Comment: Not sure if this is a newly available option, but it is also possible to specify the feature file name and line number, e.g. `bin/behat features/file.feature:123` where 123 is the line number of the line like `Scenario: Clear cache`.

Comment: You can even lauch tests on a range of lines, as explained in `bin/behat --help`: `*.feature:10-*`, `*.feature:10-20`

Answer (score 5):

Found out you can simply tag a scenario with any custom tag, for example `@foobar`.

```
Feature:
  @api @foobar
  Scenario: Clear cache
    Given the cache has been cleared
    When I am on the homepage
    Then I should get a "200" HTTP response

  Scenario:
    Given I am not logged in
    When I am on the homepage
    Then I should see the text "We love our users"
```

And then have only this scenarios run with:

```
behat --tags foobar
```

Answer (score 1):

I find that I have to use the full path to the feature file only when executing a specific scenario. For example, if your feature file was in /var/www/html/tests/features/features, and your in /var/www/html/tests then try this command:

```
bin/behat /var/www/html/tests/features/features/baseline.feature:3
```